# How to display more than 1 chart on the same page when using Google Chart Tools?

Tags: 7, views, charts

I have created a simple page (in Views) listing a series of nodes. Each node has an (EVA) field showing a pie chart.

When I use the [Google Chart Tools](https://www.drupal.org/project/google_chart_tools) module as a Views field format, the page shows only 1 chart (to the most recent node).

It seems that I need to do something so that multiple charts can show in the same page. **But what am I missing here?**

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to achieve this using the dev version of the [Views Dataviz module](http://drupal.org/project/views_dataviz). Of course there are other solutions but these require coding so i guess this is the easiest way of showing multiple charts in the same page.

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to place multiple charts on the same page at some point, through code. Just by mixing html code with the returned code from the charts worked for me. 
In case this is of any help, which might not be the case here since you use views.

You can just create your custom module and on one of the functions have something like the example found in the [Google Charts tools](http://drupal.org/project/google_chart_tools) module, where you can get a chart with `draw_chart($settings)`.

```
chart_a = draw_chart($settings_a);
$chart_b = draw_chart($settings_b);
return '<div id="chart-a">'.$chart_a.'</div>'.'<div id="chart-b">'.$chart_b.'</div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question about "But what am I missing here?": it seems that what might be the answer is what is described in the issue about [Can't display more than 1 chart at the same page](https://www.drupal.org/node/1914372). More specifically, this is what is included in [comment #2 in it](https://www.drupal.org/node/1914372#comment-7222810):

> **Turn on Aggregation** in Views, (Advance section of views). Then there will be a setting on the field called "**Aggregation Settings**". And then in the field "Aggregation Type" select "**Group Results Together**". Watch your overrides.

Give it a try and see what happens ...